# Issue with Connecting MongoDB Database in Express.js App - MERN project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, database-connection

I'm currently working on an Express.js application where I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB database using Mongoose. However, I'm encountering an issue with the database connection and need some help troubleshooting it. Here are the details:

I have an Express.js application where I'm using Mongoose to connect to a MongoDB database. I've followed the standard steps to set up the database connection, but I'm getting an error when trying to interact with the database.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/library_db', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Other routes and middleware...

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Backend Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});


  // POST /book
  app.post('/book', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { name, isbn, author } = req.body;
      const book = new Book({ name, isbn, author });
      await book.save();
      res.status(201).json(book);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
    }
  });
```

frontend CreateBook.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function CreateBook() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [isbn, setIsbn] = useState('');
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newBook = {
      name,
      isbn,
      author,
    };

    axios.post('/book', newBook)
      .then(response => {
        setMessage('Book created successfully');
        setName('');
        setIsbn('');
        setAuthor('');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        setMessage('An error occurred while creating the book');
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-4">
      <h2>Create Book</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label className="form-label">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} required />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label className="form-label">ISBN:</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" value={isbn} onChange={e => setIsbn(e.target.value)} required />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <label className="form-label">Author:</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" value={author} onChange={e => setAuthor(e.target.value)} required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create Book</button>
      </form>
      <p className="mt-3">{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateBook;
```

[image: Codse hierarchy]
[image: Frontend View]
[image: network tab details]
[image: Network tab Headeers details]
[image: frontend cmd output]
[image: backend cmd output]

Answer (score 0):

check your route and server port. problem is there in route.

Comment: Which Route?, this is my code App.js in frontend.

Comment: <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={BookList} />
          <Route exact path="/books" component={BookList} />
          <Route path="/books/:id" component={BookDetails} />
          <Route exact path="/authors" component={AuthorList} />
          <Route path="/authors/:id" component={AuthorDetails} />
          <Route path="/create-book" component={CreateBook} />
          <Route path="/create-author" component={CreateAuthor} />
        </Switch>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).